# Flow rate and Pressure

Tags: plumbing

IF FLOW RATE AT 1 IN PIPE (AT WATER METER) IS 55 GAL PER MINUTE AND PRESSURE IS 60 LBS PER SQUARE IN GOING IN TO A 2 INCH PIPE, WHAT IS FLOW RATE AND PRESSURE AT A DISTANCE OF 1500 FT WITH NO CHANGE IN ELEVATION

Comment: HEY BUDDY YOUR CAPS LOCK IS STUCK ON! Please fix it, it's quite annoying to read.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not only does it not provide enough information to accurately give an answer, it seems to be a theoretical question and not related to an actual home improvement issue.

Comment: I don't have enough rep for a close vote, but I can't disagree with @JimmyFix-it.  Please clarify the question and add more information.  And PLEASE get rid of the caps!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 4):

The flow in = the flow out, period, unless there are leaks. and those are actually just other flows out...

Assuming plastic pipe, a total dynamic head calculator indicates the TDH for this flow and distance in 2" pipe as 83 feet. New steel, 128 feet; old steel 162 feet, corroded steel 268 feet and rubber lined at 126 feet (friction due to flow rate and smoothness of pipe walls.

2.31 feet of head = 1 PSI.

So, if the 2" pipe is open ended, the pressure at the input end is about 36 PSI for plastic pipe, about 55 PSI for new steel or rubber-lined pipe, 70 for old steel and 116 for corroded steel pipe (if input pressure is 60 PSI, actual result is flow rate reduces until the TDH for the flow rate matches the input pressure.) The **pressure at the output end is 0 in all cases**, unless there is a restriction, and that restriction changes the rest of the math.

Answer (score 1):

A 1" pipe flowing into a 2" pipe that has no elevation change or restriction and is open-ended will have ZERO pressure (psig) in the 2" pipe at 1500ft., because pressure is actually **back-pressure**. It's like "throwing a hotdog down a hallway". Flow rate would be unchanged.

Not sure if your scenario is related to a "real world" problem or not; if so, you have not provided enough information.

Comment: I get that flow rate would not change, but I'm unclear on your assertion about no pressure being present. The situation is akin to a brake line acting on a slave cylinder, where pressure increases proportionally to cross-sectional area, no?

Comment: In the brake cylinder case the flow rate is negligible so the fluid is static and the pressure is constant throughout the hydraulic system. The *force* (pressure x area) on the wheel pistons is greater than on the master cylinder because the *area* of the master cylinder is *less* than the wheel cylinder.

Comment: Friction with the sidewalls will create a pressure drop in the 2 inch pipe which depends on the flowrate. The pressure at the outlet will be atmospheric because it's open to the atmosphere, thus zero 0 psig.  You can then either specify the flowrate and calculate the required pressure at the beginning of the pipe, or specify the pressure at the beginning of the pipe and calculate the flowrate.  You can't specify both.  As @fixer1234 noted, the pressure at the beginning of the pipe actually depends on the configuration of the 1 inch pipe - how long it is, how many bends, etc.

Comment: @isherwood, unless the OP gives more information it is not possible to assume that this is a hydraulically static closed system where pressure would actually increase until equal throughout the system. Not enough info even for theoretical discussion, voting to close.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - if it was a hydraulically static closed system the answer would be self-evident that the flow at 1500 ft is zero and the pressure is the inlet pressure.  It seems quite clear that it's an open system.  Nonetheless, there's still not enough information to fully answer the question.

Comment: @Mark, he (isherwood) stated that the "situation is akin to a brake line acting on a slave cylinder" so apparently it was **not** self evident to him, that is what I was pointing out. Also, the OP did not state that it was an "open system" either, it is simply a crappy question. With an incomplete or poorly worded question it is no surprise that there are different interpretations. Please vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

My long ago and casual acquaintance with fluid dynamics tells me that the pressure in the 2 inch diameter pipe would be *greater* than that in the 1 in diameter pipe. Assuming an incompressible fluid the volume flow rate in the 2 in pipe is the same as in the 1 in pipe, but the linear flow rate is 1/4 as much as in the 1 inch pipe. This increases the pressure by some considerable amount, but I don't know how to calculate how much the increase is.

**Edit**

I based my answer on the [Venturi effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect). Given the OP's specifications I assumed that there was a restriction after 1500 ft of the 2" dia pipe which limits the flow to 55 gal/min when the pressure in the run of 1" dia pipe is 60 psig.

Under these conditions the Venturi principle dictates that the pressure in the 2" dia pipe is higher than that in the 1" dia pipe, because the linear flow rate is much lower in the 2" dia pipe.

The apparent paradox of fluid flowing from a region of lower pressure (1" pipe) to a region of higher pressure (2" pipe) I think is resolved by considering the momentum (and maybe the  kinetic energy) imparted to the fluid by a pump or a pressure reservoir at the end of the 1" pipe.

However, I now see that *maybe* the OP envisioned an open end at 1500 ft in the 2" pipe so in that case the pressure there would be 0 psig and the flow would be 55 gal/min. In that case the pressure everywhere in the 2" pipe would be much lower (maybe even 0 psig) than the 60 psig in the 1" pipe.

We need more information from the OP.

Comment: That's only in a closed system, which you don't have if the water is flowing.

Comment: If the pressure in the 2 inch pipe is higher, the water will flow from the 2 inch pipe to the 1 inch pipe.

Comment: @Mark I edited my answer to reference the Venturi effect as the basis for my claim.